# Python 2.7 Twitter Scraper

Tags: python, tweepy

When I change the end time of my cursor to the 29th it returns 0 for everything. But when I change it to the 28th I get all the information.

```
start = "2017-02-25"
    end = "2017-02-29"
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=i,since=start,until=end,lang="en").items():

        parsed = status._json
        usercount[parsed['user']['name'].encode("utf-8")]+=1
        userfollowers[parsed['user']['name'].encode("utf-8")]= parsed['user']['followers_count']
        mostretweets[parsed['text'].encode('utf-8')] = parsed['retweet_count']         
        mostfav[parsed['text'].encode('utf-8')] = parsed['favorite_count']
```

Comment: there are only 28 days in feb(2)...unless it's a leap year which 2017 isn't

Comment: What, specifically, are you looking for help with?  `2017-02-29` isn't a valid date.

Answer (score 2):

29th of February does not exist (at least in 2017), that is not a valid date...

Answer (score 2):

Seek to use `datetime`, so there will already be a validation of the date.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2017, 2, 29)

ValueError: day is out of range for month

start = datetime(2017, 2, 25).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime(2017, 2, 28).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```